# Create numeric matrix with variables

Tags: r, matrix

I don't know how to create matrix with numbers and variables. Here is my example: Matrix A is ok, B is a problem, because y is not defined.

```
A<-matrix(c(2,-3,-3,6),2,2)
B<-matrix(c(1,0,y,1),2,2)
```

If I could create B, I would multiply this 2 matrixes and get the result for B%*%A:

```
= [2-3y -3+y]
  [-3     6 ]
```

Comment: Do you want to do symbolic calculation? Then you'd need a computer algebra system such as YACAS, which you can interface with R using the Ryacas package.

Comment: After insttaling YACAS you can do something like : `yacas("A:={ {2,-3},{-3,6}}") ;yacas("B:={ {1,0},{y,1}}");yacas("A*B")
`

Comment: Yes YACAS look good option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, matrices in R can only hold numeric values. Is there a reason you do not want to define y before doing this calculation? For example, you could do:

```
y=3
A=matrix(c(2,-3,-3,6),nrow=2)
B=matrix(c(1,0,y,1),nrow=2)
A%*%B
```

to get the answer:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]   -3   -3
```

Comment: I forgot add rows. Problem is only variable

Comment: Actually they can hold any data type (but not more than one). You can have a matrix of characters for example.